# Start intent activity back to same activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am creating an application, surprising I know, and using a quick back button to return the user to a previous listing.  The code below is the intent portion that starts the activity.  Now it is sending the activity back to itself with an "LvPos" variable to determine which position it just re-start itself at.

```
Spinner spinMe = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
                                    Intent backIntent = new Intent(null, null, getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
                                    int itemSelected = spinMe.getSelectedItemPosition();
                                    backIntent.putExtra("LvPos", itemSelected);
                                    startActivity(backIntent);
```

Now the code below is the reference in the onCreate method that gets teh LvPos variable.  The problem is, when I get to this portion, the LvPos is null.  I have the same code for various other intents and all work fine.  If anyone can see any glaring issues, let me know as I have to be severely overlooking something.

```
int positionID = 0;
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null){
    String LvPosBundle = extras.getString("LvPos");

    if (LvPosBundle != null)
        positionID = Integer.parseInt(LvPosBundle);
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are Using the putExtra(String, int) when you are putting the extra.

When retrieving you use:

```
extras.getString("LvPos");
```

instead use:

```
extras.getInt("LvPos");
```

Store that in an integer instead of string. Then you also don't have to do the parseInt.

Hope this Helps.

-Travis

Comment: I knew it was something so simple, I was just completely over looking it.  It is the easiest ones, through all the other more complex code, that gets the best of a programmer at times.   You would think that would throw an error but useful information I will never forget.

Comment: That is true my friend. Good luck with your projects.